# Navigate to next symbol, in IntelliJ idea (pycharm, rubymine, etc)?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, rubymine

In  IntelliJ idea, one can navigate to a symbol using Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N and the docs are here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html

Is there a shortcut way to visit the "next" symbol in the list?
A possible use case would be "visit every underscore underscore *unicode* method in my project".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the dialog is opened, click on the pin (Show All in View). You can then use the shortcut "Next Occurrence" (ctrl+alt+down).

Comment: Perfect.  Note Gnome shortcut is shift+alt+down.